# Loading an interstital Ad on a timer with a loading page with navigation app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm looking to show a screen (non-interactive) to show for a few seconds, before presenting an interstitial ad.
At the moment, my interstitial is called using a method

```
[self showStartupAd];
```

Which shows this; which of course shows the ad.

```
-(void)showStartupAd{
    UIViewController *rootController = self.window.rootViewController;
    [IronSource showInterstitialWithViewController:rootController placement:0];
}
```

However, I would like to show a basic timer, say, to show for 5 seconds, an activityview or indicator of some sort, that launches first, which allows the user to see a short text (such as 'Sponsored ad loading' and then have a method for when the timer ends/view dismisses, to then show the ad (I can then handle the rest in the ad callbacks).

I can of course get a progress view showing like this;

```
UIViewController *rootController = self.window.rootViewController;
    
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
indicator.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 140.0, 140.0);
indicator.center = rootController.view.center;
[rootController.view addSubview:indicator];
[indicator bringSubviewToFront:rootController.view];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;

[indicator startAnimating];
```

But this doesn't show any kind of screen I can customise / use callbacks from.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the initial view controller is not a UINavigationController:

1. Put the content you wish to show on the initial view controller
2. On that same view controller, override *viewDidAppear* and add a dispatch-after block with whatever delay you would like (see https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/objectivec/dispatch+after+objective+c)
3. Inside the dispatch block, put *showStartupAd*